# pattern-A but not overlapping with pattern-B

Tags: python, regex, pcre

Given an arbitrary string of words (for simplicity each letter represents a word):
`a b c d e f c g e b c f d g`

I am trying to find a regex that allows me to match an expression (word `b` followed by word `f` with a distance of max 3 words), but not when overlapping with another expression (word `c` followed by word `e` with a distance of max 3 words).

and given the pattern-A to match `b\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}f`
(would match `b c d e f`and `b c f`)
and the not to overlap pattern-B `c\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}e` and pattern-C `d\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}g`
is there a combined regex to match `b c f` but not `b c d e f` because the latter is overlapping with pattern-B (`c d e`)
or because there is a partial overlap with pattern-C (`d e f c g`)?

I have added the string and patterns in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UWcPC4/2) for convenience.

I am using the python [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module (PCRE). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you want to prevent or require a match at a point according to a pattern and don't want that pattern to consume anything, [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) are a potential solution. Indeed, all that's needed is to put patterns B and C as [negative lookaheads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-21) in the position where you want to prevent matches (i.e. immediately before a word that's between the 'b' and 'f').

An outline of the pattern:

```
\b(b\s+(?:(?!{pattern-B}|{pattern-C})\w+\s+){1,3}f)\b
```

Note word boundary anchors have been added before the first word and after the last.

With the other patterns substituted in, the whole regex becomes (in [free-spacing mode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html)):

```
\b(
  b\s+
  (?:
    # will prevent matching both contained and 
    # partially overlapped c-e and d-g patterns
    (?!c\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}e
      |d\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}g)
    \w+\s+
  ){1,3}
  f
|
  c\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}e
|
  d\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,3}g
)\b
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/G0jWo2/4))

Lookbehinds in python's `re` module are limited to having a fixed length, which requires [special handling to achieve some results](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind).

Negative lookarounds won't always work as you might expect. For example, within repetitions, they can prevent matching in one position, but at that point the regex engine will in general then try other positions (possessive quantifiers being the exception), where it might succeed.

For another example, alternate negative lookarounds (e.g. `((?!A)|(?!B))`) will have no effect, since a failure on one branch means the other will succeed. Instead, simply concatenate the negative lookarounds (e.g. `(?!A)(?!B)`). This comes up when you have negative lookbehinds of different lengths (e.g. `(?<!\ba\b)(?<!\bthe\b)`).

Comment: I could use the above solution for cases when I know pattern-A advance. Most of the times though, pattern A is generated from a DSL and not known in advance, so using lookarounds inside pattern A will not be possible, or at least not without a deeper analysis thereof.<br/>

I try to give the example from another angle.

Comment: The aim is to discard the following overlapping cases when looking for pattern A:

1. `b x c x e x f` pattern A (b-f) covers pattern B (c-e) entirely

2. `c x b x f x e` pattern A (b-f) is covered by B (c-e) entirely

3. `b x c x f x e` pattern A partially overlaps with B.

4. `c x b x e x f` pattern B partially overlaps with A


In all cases the pattern to be looked for is A, but not when overlapped as in the above 4 cases. Assume that patterns A and B are generated dynamically and bounded by \b.

Comment: The partial solution solving cases 2 and 4 I could come up with so far, without having to dissect pattern A is the following:  
```
\b
  c\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,5}e
\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
\b
  b\s+(?:\S+\s+){1,5}f
\b
```
([demo](https://regex101.com/r/F9dshx/2))
Cases 1 and 3 are the ones I am looking a solution for, without having to analyse the content of pattern A, which is generated from user input.
I am out of ideas here.

Comment: @mattkeanny: Outside of asking for clarification, [comments](/help/privileges/comment) shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: If you have additional requirements that aren't yet described in the question, [edit] the question rather than posting a comment. If you have questions beyond what you originally asked (which looks to be the case here), first check whether the question has already been asked, and post a new question if not. See "[When to ask a new question or edit an old question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317446/90527)", "["Follow on" question vs edit to original - when to use which?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746/90527)"

Comment: @mattkeanny ``The partial solution solving cases 2 and 4``. It seems this solution can work wrong if you use not only c-e but also d-g overlapping rule.