# Find text fragment with Regex A that can't be overlapped by regex B

Tags: regex, pcre

I continue to learn advanced PCRE techniques.
Please help me make a regex (or inform about impossibility) for the following task:

**For any patterns A and B, find a text fragment that would correspond to A, and could not be overlapped by B.**

The desired regex should be inserted into underlying expression instead the `<...>`

```
<...>(?(DEFINE)(?'A'<pattern A>)(?'B'<pattern B>))
```

This should be some generalized case of [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720331/pattern-a-but-not-overlapping-with-pattern-b) that will be able to work with almost any patterns A and B.

I try different variants but failed.

Comment: II feel that you will ask more and more difficult questions until we all together hit the ceiling of PCRE's capabilities :)  This question is interesting. When I have more time I will think about solution if someone doesn't do it sooner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can imagine something like this:

```
^(?*(.*?)(((?&A))(.*+)))(?!  # Try all possible variants of A
   .*?(?(?=.*?\2$)
      (?&B)(?!.*?\2$)  # B started before the beginning of A or together with the beginning of A, and ended after the beginning of A
      |
      (?=.+?\4$)(?&B)  # B started after the beginning of A, but before the end of A
))\1\K\3(?(DEFINE)(?<A>\w+)(?<B>\d))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVeRa2/1)

Comment: It works! Your techniques are awesome! Thank you for sharing them

Comment: Nice use of napla.